# Creating Connection Pool In Standalone Java Application

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, pool

I need to use a connection pool in a standalone (as in non-web) Java application.  Where I work, we are not allowed to use APIs without going through layers of security, and the job needs to be completed soon.  Below is my attempt at creating this connection pool.

I have unit tested this code and tested it within the context of the overall application a hundred times and in all cases the tests passed with zero errors, and in addition the performance of each run is just under three thousand times faster than a simple connect, retrieve data, disconnect in serial approach; however, I still have nagging concerns that there could be issues with this approach that I simply haven't unearthed yet.  I would appreciate any advice anyone has concerning the below code.  This is my first post on this site; please let me know if I've made any errors in etiquette.  I did search this site about this problem before posting.  Please see below the code for an invocation example.  Thanks.  --JR

```
package mypackage;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Note: This class is only instantiated once per application run.
 *       Multiple instantiations, as specified in the release notes,
 *       are not supported.      
 */
public class ConnectionManager {

    // Use a blocking queue to store the database connections.
    // The application will only be called once, by a single user,
    // but within the application many threads will require 
    // a connection. 
    private BlockingQueue<Connection> connectionQueue = null;

    // Load the connection queue with a user-defined number of connections.
    // Params contains a map of all non hard-coded variables in the
    // application.
    public ConnectionManager(int howMany, Map<String, Object> params) {
        Database database = new Database();
        connectionQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Connection>(howMany);
        for(int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
            connectionQueue.add(database.getConn(params));
        }
    }

    // Return a connection from the queue, waiting up to 15 minutes to do so.
    // 15 minutes is hard-coded because it is the standard time-out for all
    // processes at our agency.  This application must complete in less
    // than fifteen minutes (is currently completing in thirty five seconds).
    public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = connectionQueue.poll(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }

    // Returns a connection to the connection queue.  
    public void returnConnectionToManager(Connection conn) {
        connectionQueue.add(conn);
    }

    // Called on the last line of the application program's dispatcher.
    // Closes all active connections (which will only exist if there
    // was a failure within one of the worker threads).
    public void closeAllConnections() {
        for(Connection conn : connectionQueue) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Invocation example:

...

```
private ConnectionManager cm;
```

...

```
public Table(Map<String, Object> params, String method) {
  ...
  cm = (ConnectionManager) params.get("cm");
}

// Execute a chunk of SQL code without requiring processing of a 
// result set.  Acquires connection from pool via cm.getConnection
// and releases connection via cm.returnConnectionToManager.
// (Database is just a helper class with simple methods for 
// closing prepared statement, result sets, etc.)  
private void execute(String sql) {
  PreparedStatement ps = null;
  Connection conn = null;
  try {
    conn = cm.getConnection();
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.execute();
  }
  catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally {
    database.closePreparedStatement(ps);
    cm.returnConnectionToManager(conn); 
  }
}
```

Comment: store the object into a singleton class or enum. Prefarably enum. In this way your connection pool would be easily accessible and avoid multiple objects easily. Add a method to release individual connection after you application code is finished with DB transaction.

Comment: `Where I work, we are not allowed to use APIs without going through layers of security` ..sounds like a bad case of Not Invented Here. It always amazes me why some people think that in-house code is somehow safer than open source frameworks tried and tested by thousands of people.

Comment: IMO rather than writing your own code getting the API cleared would be better

Comment: Make a one place in which you posts your queries to execute, in this place take connection, execute query and return the connection to the pool. It will secure you that the connections are returned. If you need to invoke multiple queries one after another in a single connection make the method accept an array or list of SQL queries to execute in order.

Comment: Ace, I wish I had the option of getting an API for this cleared, but it almost takes an Act of Congress to make that happen.  After ten years, I've given up even trying anymore.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, but there is one serious problem, that clients of your API needs to take care of getting and releasing connection, one of them forget, and memory/resource leak is ready.

Make a one place in which you posts your queries to execute, in this place take connection, execute query and return the connection to the pool. It will secure you that the connections are returned. If you need to invoke multiple queries one after another in a single connection make the method accept an array or list of SQL queries to execute in order. The idea is to encapsulate each request to the db, so you manage all connections. It could be donethat you write an interface that has en execute(Connection conn) which you need to implement, and you could have then some Service that takes such object gives it a connection and then releases the resources back to connection pool.
Something like:

```
interface SqlWork {
 execute(Connection conn);
}

SqlWork myWork = new SqlWork () {
  execute(Connection conn) {
    // do you work with the conn here
  }
}

class SqlExecutionService {
   ConnectionManager cm = ...;

   public void execute(SqlWork sqlWork) {
       Connection conn = null;
       try {
         conn = cm.getConnection();
         sqlWork.execute(conn);
       } catch (Your exceptions here) {
         //serve or rethrow them
       }
       finally 
       {
         if (conn!=null) { 
           cm.returnConnectionToManager(conn); 
         }
       }
   }
}
```

Example of use:

```
SqlExecutionService sqlExecService = ...;
sqlExecService.execute(myWork);
```

Comment: Thanks, Krzysztof.  One thing I didn't mention is that no one else will use this code--they are only allowed to run it.  So I don't have to worry about anyone misusing it; only running it incorrectly (in which case any issues fall on them; that sounds bad, but it just kind of the way it is where I work--everyone has to protect himself, because on one else will look out for him).  Thanks for the code and your insight.  Much appreciated.

Comment: That seems to be valid point :) but I assure you that this approch will save your time in the future, I've often forget to do something if it isn't automatic.